# What is the purpose of OPTLOCK in jBPM 6.2?

Tags: jbpm

What is the purpose of `OPTLOCK` in jBPM 6.2? I've looked at https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-persistence-jpa/src/main/java/org/jbpm/persistence/processinstance/ProcessInstanceInfo.java#L54, it seems to store a version variable, but not much documentation is found on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a column used by JPA in cases where optimistic locking is used. It basically contains a numeric number which is incremented every time jBPM persists the process instance. If the same process instance is read concurrently from two different threads and then modified and persisted, the last attempt will fail because the version number would have been incremented by the first attempt. For more info see: https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and